# Unschedule update in Cocos2d js

Tags: schedule, cocos2d-js

Hi in my cocos2d js application i am using 'this.scheduleUpdate()' which works fine but when i use this.unscheduleUpdate() it dosent seem to work and hangs the application.
Could someone tell me how to make it work...I am sharing the code below.
Thanks.

```
var HelloWorldLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
    sprite:null,
    ctor:function () {

        this._super();

        var cal=function(){
            this.unscheduleUpdate();
        }

        this.scheduleUpdate();

        cal();

        return true;
    },

    update:function(dt){
        cc.log("schedule "+dt);
    }
});

var HelloWorldScene = cc.Scene.extend({
    onEnter:function () {
        this._super();
        var layer = new HelloWorldLayer();
        this.addChild(layer);
    }
});
```

Comment: try
this.unschedule(update);

Comment: That dosent work either...I tried the same using a custom call back but the same result.... @sortris

Comment: So try this.schedule(update) and next this.unschedule(update). It works for me everytime :)

Comment: It works when i call them one after another...I want to call unschedule inside a function which is called when game over...That way dosent seem to work..? @sortris

Comment: when i use this.unschedule(update) i get error update not defined,but its gets sheduled perfectly... @sortris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely running into a scope issue. `this` within that function is not referring to your layer, the following should work:

Replace:

```
var cal=function(){
    this.unscheduleUpdate();
}
```

With:

```
var that = this;
var cal = function() {
    that.unscheduleUpdate();
};
```